# Como iterar em um model em C# com variáveis que tem número?

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho um model que foi feito por outro desenvolvedor onde tem diversos campos assim:

.
.
.

```
Teste() teste = new Teste();
teste.campo_1 = 1;
teste.campo_2 = 2;
teste.campo_3 = 3;
teste.campo_4 = 4;
teste.campo_5 = 5;
```

Como faria para preencher os dados usando o for?

Comment: Não vejo o que isso tem a ver com *model*, de qualquer forma, é simples, faça isto ser uma lista, *array*, ou algo assim, que é o certo a se fazer, afinal está claro que isto é uma informação única com variantes, é o exemplo claro que as variáveis deveriam ser encapsuladas em uma única variável. Se não puder fazer isto, aí terá que usar reflexão, e será uma enorme gambiarra.

Comment: @RonaldoPeres Não é.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) disse em seu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269614/como-iterar-em-um-model-em-c-com-vari%C3%A1veis-que-tem-n%C3%BAmero#comment552253_269614), é necessário usar reflexão para fazer isso. Caso você não consiga realizar as modificações que ele sugeriu, o seguinte código funciona e pode te ajudar.

```
public class Teste
{
    public int campo_1 { get; set; }
    public int campo_2 { get; set; }
    public int campo_3 { get; set; }
    public int campo_4 { get; set; }
    public int campo_5 { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var teste = new Teste();
        var type = teste.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var valor = property.Name.Substring(property.Name.IndexOf("_") + 1);

            Console.WriteLine("Propriedade: " + property.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Valor antes: " + property.GetValue(teste, null));

            property.SetValue(teste, Int32.Parse(valor));

            Console.WriteLine("Valor depois: " + property.GetValue(teste, null));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Também veja funcionando [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gZWYDB)

Comment: Obrigado, creio que é isso mesmo

Answer (score 5):

O certo seria transformar esse monte de propriedades em uma coleção (array, list ou similares).

```
public class Teste
{
    public List<int> Campos { get; } = new List<int>();
}
```

Assim, você não precisa alterar o modelo toda a vez que precisar de um campo novo, além de que, parece fazer muito mais sentido.

Pra usar, você pode fazer assim:

```
var obj = new Teste();
for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
{
    obj.Campos.Add(i);
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0NpEz4)</sup>

Se você realmente não puder fazer isto, vai ter que usar reflexão, basicamente vai precisar do método `SetValue` de `PropertyInfo`.

Por exemplo:

```
var obj = new Teste();
string propBase = "campo_";

for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    var propName = propBase + i;
    typeof(Teste).GetProperty(propName).SetValue(obj, i, null);
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MuOanM)</sup>

Comment: A primeira solução da resposta é a correta, a segunda é gambiarra que resolve quando já está errado ;)

Comment: @Maniero Sim, parece que o AP está mais interessado na gambiarra do que na solução.